# excluding fields from json serialization in python using jsonpickle

Tags: python, json, serialization, jsonpickle

I am using jsonpickle to serialize an object to json. The object has certain fields that point to other objects. I'd like to selectively *not* include those in the serialization, so that the resulting json file is essentially pure human-readable text without any funny representations of objects. Is there a way to make jsonpickle ignore certain object fields when serialization? Or more generally, include only fields that are "primitive" or easily serializable fields, like dictionaries, ints, lists of dicts, etc.

thanks.

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147435/how-to-exclude-specific-fields-on-serialization-with-jsonpickle).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you might be looking for is the unpicklable argument (see [this doc](http://jsonpickle.github.com/api.html#jsonpickle-high-level-api) for details). In short, if this argument is set to `False`, jsonpickle will not output custom python classes to JSON. It should only output JSON native types e.g strings, ints, bools and lists.