# How to exclude specific fields on serialization with jsonpickle?

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy, flask, jsonpickle

I'm using SQLAlchemy extension with Flask. While serializing my models *(which are also used for database operations)* using jsonpickle, I want some specific attributes to be ignored. Is there a way that allows me to set those rules?

SQLAlchemy adds an attribute named `_sa_instance_state` to the object. In a word, I do not want this field to be in the JSON output.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You cannot tell the default class pickler to ignore something, no.

`jsonpickle` *does* support the [`pickle` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) [`__getstate__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) and [`__setstate__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__) methods. If your classes implement those two methods, whatever is returned is then used by `jsonpickle` to represent the state instead. Both methods do need to be implemented.

If `__getstate__` is *not* implemented, `jsonpickle` uses the `__dict__` attribute instead, so your own version merely needs to use that same dictionary, remove the `_sa_instance_state` key and you are done:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    state = self.__dict__.copy()
    del state['_sa_instance_state']
    return state

def __setstate__(self, state):
    self.__dict__.update(state)
```

Whatever `__getstate__` returns will be processed further, recursively, there is no need to worry about handling subobjects there.

If adding `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` is not an option, you can also register a [custom serialization handler](http://jsonpickle.github.io/api.html#jsonpickle-handlers-custom-serialization-handlers) for your class; the disadvantage is that while `__getstate__` can get away with just returning a dictionary, a custom handler will need to return a fully flattened value.

Comment: Adding `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` works like a charm for now, thank you. Instead of writing same lines of code for each model, implementing a decorator to remove ignored fields from `__dict__` might be a good idea for the future.

Comment: I second what mkubilayk desires for a future feature, it would be very much analogous to .NET's xml serialization's [XmlAttributes.XmlIgnore Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This one will help others to get their task done:

Make a class like this one in a package like your custom `jsonpickle` package:

```
class SetGetState:
    def __getstate__(self):
        state = self.__dict__.copy()
        try:
            class_name = '_' + self.__class__.__name__ + '__'
            new_items = {key:value for key, value in state.items() if class_name not in key}
            return new_items
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return state
```

And inherit this one in the class requires no private property serialization

```
class Availability(jsonpickle.SetGetState):
    pass
```